# Are there any downside in investing in a municipal money fund instead of purchasing municipal bonds assuming the money fund's yield > muni bond yield?

Tags: investing, bonds, mutual-funds, money-market, municipal-bonds

I wonder whether there exists any downsides in investing in a municipal money fund instead of purchasing municipal bond, assuming the money fund's yield (tax-free) is higher than the muni bond yield (tax-free)?

The only downside in investing in a municipal money fund I can think of if is the yield decreases, whereas for the municipal bond, the yield stays the same until it matures. Let's ignore the municipal money fund's expense ratio and the markups, commissions, transaction fees or contract fees when purchasing bonds or municipal money fund.

Example: Schwab Municipal Money Fund (Investor Shares) ([SWTXX](https://www.schwabfunds.com/products/SWTXX)) has a 7-day yield (with waivers) as of 02/24/2023 of 3.17% (tax-free), whereas 3-month AAA municipal bonds have a yield-to-maturity of 2.81% (tax-free) or lower, as shown in the screenshot below from [Charles Schwab](https://client.schwab.com/app/research/fixed-income-hub/#/home). If one assumes that the yield of future municipal bonds remains constant constant or increase, is there any downside in investing investing in the municipal money fund SWTXX instead of purchasing the 3-month AAA municipal bond?

[image]

Comment: *assuming the money fund's yield > muni bond yield* - well, if you assume that, then... But why would you assume such a thing?

Comment: @littleadv I added an example with SWTXX yield (tax-free) > 3-month AAA municipal bond yield (tax-free).

Comment: VTC: why opinion-based? It's just maths+taxes+maybe some other components I overlooked (hence this question).

Comment: Anecdotal example of a specific day snapshot means nothing. Why would you assume that funds that hold the bond will yield more than the bond itself? Explain your logic to me.

Comment: @littleadv different maturity dates, for example. I showed a specific day snapshot, which I am trying to understand.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you're making a lot of assumptions and are essentially asking for investment advice, when it's not clear what your goal is.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD my goal is understanding the downsides in investing in a municipal money fund instead of purchasing municipal bonds directly.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt what's larger - apples or oranges? You're comparing two absolutely different things, and on a random day a measurement of these things satisfies a ">" relation. Does it mean that it will always be so? If you pick a barely grown orange which is 1mm in diameter and compare it to a ripe huge granny smith - can you assume that apples are always larger?

Comment: @littleadv What's unclear in my example?

Comment: It is not examplifying anything. You're showing a fund holds bonds A,B,C,D collectively yielding value *α*, comparing it to a bond Z yielding value *ω* and concluding that relationship between holding *any* bond fund and *any* bond would be the same as the relationship between these *α* and *ω*.

Comment: @littleadv I'm not making any conclusion, I'm just asking for downsides of purchasing the fund instead of the bond.

Comment: so what does this sentence mean: *assuming the money fund's yield (tax-free) is higher than the muni bond yield (tax-free)*? What did you want to say here?

Comment: @littleadv In the example, money fund's yield (tax-free) is 3.17% and the muni bond yield (tax-free) is 2.81%. That's one example where the  assumption holds. We also assume that the yield of future municipal bonds remains constant constant or increases.

Comment: I think I understand your mistake. You think that "yield" is a thing. I suggest maybe you look up the definition of "yield". The fact that both the fund and the bond have "yield" attribute doesn't mean that they're comparable.

Comment: @littleadv I  assume that so that we eliminate the downside "municipal money fund yield may decrease whereas the yield of a bond won't change".

Comment: Wait, what? What does it even mean?

Comment: @littleadv https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/mutual-fund-yield.asp#:~:text=A%20mutual%20fund's%20yield%20refers,the%20share's%20net%20asset%20value.: "Mutual fund yield is expressed as a percentage based on the income amount per share divided by the share's net asset value.". https://www.desjardins.com/ca/co-opme/action-plans-tips/savings-investment/understanding-bond-yields/index.jsp#:~:text=Yield%20is%20a%20figure%20that,changes%2C%20so%20does%20the%20yield.: "yield = coupon amount/price". Isn't that comparable? (honest question)

Comment: You realize that you quoted two different definitions, right? Yield for funds is one thing, yield for bond is another thing, and they're not the same thing. Read this: *There are various types of yield, and the method of calculation depends on the particular type of yield and the type of security. Because of these differences, yield comparisons between different types of financial products should be treated with caution* (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(finance)))

Comment: @littleadv Thanks. [How can one compare the yield of a municipal money fund with the yield of a municipal bond?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155590/5656). For the question "Are there any downside in investing in a municipal money fund instead of purchasing municipal bonds assuming the money fund's yield > muni bond yield?", let's assume the yields are comparable.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: am I correct in guessing English isn't your native language? If not, folks may need to be a bit more explicit so ideas survive translation.

Comment: @keshlam correct. What's unclear?

Comment: @littleadv just wanted to make sure they aren't any other downsides. No downsides is a valid answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one compare the yield of a municipal money fund with the yield of a municipal bond?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155590/how-can-one-compare-the-yield-of-a-municipal-money-fund-with-the-yield-of-a-muni)

Comment: (You asked two strongly overlapping questions at once. I believe the same answer covers both versions.)

Comment: @keshlam in this question I'm asking what's the downside if any assuming that the yield is favorable. The other question asks how the yields can be compared. That's two different questions in my opinion.

Comment: @keshlam yes. I eliminated that downside with the assumptions stated in the question, so that we can focus on other downsides, if any.

Answer (score 5):

The 7-day yield of the fund is likely a taxable yield, whereas the 2.81% of the bond you highlighted is probably tax free, giving you a tax-equivalent yield of 3.75% (assuming a 25% tax rate).

Either way, you might be better off buying a 3M CD or Treasury, given the higher yield (4.9%) and lower risk.

---

I just noticed that the Weighted Average Maturity of the fund is 10.5 days, which is quite different from a 3M maturity. What's your investment horizon?

> If one assumes that the yield of future municipal bonds remains constant constant or increase

Yields change daily. Which tenor are we talking about? Either way, if yields go up, the value of your existing holdings goes down.

Comment: Thanks, the municipal money fund is tax-free. (sorry, I forgot to add it in the question).

Comment: "Which tenor are we talking about?" In the example, I compare the municipal money fund SWTXX vs. 3-month AAA municipal bonds.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I understand that but it's not an apples-to-apples comparison and your assumptions are flawed to begin with.

Comment: There are 2 assumptions: 1) If one assumes that the yield of future municipal bonds remains constant constant or increases. 2) "assuming the money fund's yield (tax-free) is higher than the muni bond yield (tax-free)?"Which one is flawed?

Answer (score -2):

Following the question's assumptions and intentional omissions, i.e. assuming:

1. The money fund's yield (tax-free) is higher than the muni bond yield (tax-free)
2. The yield of future municipal bonds remains constant constant or increase.

And ignoring:

1. Municipal money fund's expense ratio.
2. The markups, commissions, transaction fees or contract fees when purchasing bonds or shares of the municipal money fund.

There are no downsides in investing in a municipal money fund instead of purchasing municipal bonds.

Note that the yield of a municipal money fund is not 100% comparable with the yield of a municipal bond (see [How can one compare the yield of a municipal money fund with the yield of a municipal bond?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155590/5656)), but for municipal bonds with short maturities (e.g., 3 months or below), it is very similar (the shorter the maturity of the bond, the more the yields are comparable).

Comment: Or putting it another way, the things you're ignoring and assuming away are the downsides.

Comment: @keshlam yes. I eliminated some potential downsides with the assumptions and omissions stated in the question, so that we can focus on other downsides, if any.

Comment: Just feels like an odd way to approach it rather than "what are the trade-offs" and having them all listed out for the next reader.

Comment: @keshlam Good point, I agree, I could have done that instead.